# how to insert an image to the exported report in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert an image as part of the report generated from an analysis in Excel VBA. The report   is a word document format (.doc)

The Function that export the report is as given below, which works fine for me. the only thing is I am not able to get images into the report.

```
Function FnExportToWordDoc()
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim pctCompl As Single
Dim objSelection

msg = msg & "STRESS DUE TO SUSTAINED LOAD TEST " & sustainedtest & vbNewLine
msg = msg & " " & vbNewLine
msg = msg & " The design for occassional load require that " & occtest & "<" & occright &       vbNewLine
msg = msg & " " & vbNewLine
msg = msg & " Allowable stress due to dead weight  " & Sallsus & "psi" & vbNewLine
msg = msg & " " & vbNewLine
msg = msg & "STRESS DUE TO OCCASIONAL LOAD TEST " & occtestmsg & vbNewLine
msg = msg & " " & vbNewLine   
msg = msg & "I want an image here"

reportdrs = Mypath.reportpath
reportname = Myname.reportname
reportdr = reportdrs & "\" & reportname

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

objWord.Visible = True

Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.TypeText (msg)

objDoc.SaveAs (reportdr)

msgre = "The report has been saved here " & reportdr & vbNewLine

Title = "Report Generated"
MsgBox msgre, vbOKOnly, Title


End Function
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What type of image?  A table? A graph?

Comment: any image format e.g jpeg,png,btmp etc. I have equally tried to include a table containing data as part of the report but could not achieve it, but I just felt it should be a separate question.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a Copy -> Paste?

Comment: That is where my problem is, the image I am exporting is not in any of the sheet, it's inside a folder, now how do I set the image to be copied?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Example1()
  Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
    "D:\Stuff\Business\Temp\SP_A0155.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=True
End Sub
```

Did a quick Google Search for inserting a picture into word and found the above at http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/05/13/word-vba-insert-images/